# How to produce Live video and audio streaming (not VoD) with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to produce a Live audio/video stream from local file.

I tried the following:

> ffmpeg -re -thread_queue_size 4 -i source_video_file.ts -strict -2
>   -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://localhost:10000 -acodec copy -vn -sdp_file saved_sdp_file -f rtp rtp://localhost:20000

and then:

> ffplay saved_sdp_file

It seems to work fine, but it looks like a Video on Demand, cause I can replay this file with ffplay whenever I want.

But I need ffplay to show video/audio only during ffmpeg streaming instance is running (the first command above).

How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This  code works for live video streaming :

```
proc liveStreaming {} {

    
    #ffmpeg command to capture live streaming in background
    exec ffplay -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" >& $logFile &
  
}
liveStreaming
```

Make use of fmmpeg using  following code, this also works :

```
proc liveStreaming {} {

    
    #ffmpeg command to capture live streaming
    exec ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -f sdl2 -
  
}
liveStreaming
```

You can also make use of "sdl" if sdl2 doesn't work.

Comment: You should stop using formatting using the *code snippet* (ctrl+m) and use the *code sample* (ctrl+k) instead. The code snippet is only for JavaScript/HTML/CSS and it makes no sense to use it for anything else. [Example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149850/47477) of proper use of code snippet.